# MySQL вывести строки по условиям запроса IF/ELSE CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if, case

Допустим есть такая таблица **__test_if_else**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести строки соответствующие двум условиям.

На "псевдо языке" это выглядело бы примерно вот так:

```
    // Если есть id проверяем поле lang и выводим строку начиная с первого условия
    // т.е. вывести строки с двумя идентификаторами, но если нет 'en' вместо нее вывести 'ru'
        if( id (1||2) in  table ) {
            if ( lang === 'en' in table ) {
                 return this.ROW_EN // если сошлось
            }
            else if ( lang === 'ru' in table ){
                 return this.ROW_RU // ... нет 'en' выводим 'ru'
            }
            else {
                return NULL
            }
        }
```

Пробовал CASE, но не обнаружил у него подобие BREAK,
и еще он выводит все строки с дополнительным полем после THEN.

**Неудавшиеся примеры:**

Здесь необходимо выбрать строку с lang = 'en',
так как она первая в условии.

```
SELECT *, 
CASE
  WHEN (lang = 'en' and id_not_unique = 1) THEN 1 
  WHEN (lang = 'ru' and id_not_unique = 1) THEN 1 
END AS `row`
from __test_if_else;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А здесь выбрать lang = 'ru', так как 'en' с id_not_unique=2 отсутствует.

```
SELECT *, 
CASE
  WHEN (lang = 'en' and id_not_unique = 2) THEN 1 
  WHEN (lang = 'ru' and id_not_unique = 2) THEN 1 
END AS `row`
from __test_if_else;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В примерах указал только один идентификатор, на деле их множество.

```
    id_not_unique IN (1,2 .... 1253)
```

**Как вывести только необходимые поля таблицы, с определенными идентификаторами,
но при отсутствии строки 'en'(которая проверяется первой) вывести строки с 'ru'?**

Comment: Не совсем по теме, но языки, как своего рода сущности, не надо хранить в текстовом виде. Создайте для них отдельную таблицу, а в этой табличке сохраняйте лишь id языка. На крайний случай можно использовать `enum` (если список языков никогда не изменится)

Comment: На самом деле это не для больших документов, это одна из таблиц для всплывающих подсказок, данные там очень маленькие и запросы на нее предполагаются сразу с несколькими идентификаторами. Вот я и хотел упростить, чтоб один запрос в базу вытащил сразу все данные.

Answer (score 1):

### Пока пришел к такому результату.

Есть таблица документов с разными переводами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зашел итальянец и запросил документы(1-4) на своем языке,
но вероятно всех переводов нет.
Пытаемся возвратить в порядке приоритета.

```
    SELECT N.id_not_unique, N.lang, N.document FROM __test_if_else AS N
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT S.id_not_unique, S.lang FROM
        (SELECT  id_not_unique, lang, 
            CASE lang
                WHEN 'it' THEN 0
                WHEN 'en' THEN 1
                WHEN 'fr' THEN 2
                ELSE 3
            END AS success
        from __test_if_else  WHERE id_not_unique IN (1,2,3,4) AND lang IN ( 'ru','en','it','fr' )
        ORDER BY success ) AS S 
    GROUP BY S.id_not_unique) AS U 
    ON (U.id_not_unique = N.id_not_unique AND U.lang = N.lang)
```

Надеемся что приоритет его знаний:

1. итальянский (ну это и понятно)
2. английский
3. французский
4. ну и на "крайняк" пусть учит **русский**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно кто-то напишет и покороче.

### PS Обновление.

Спасибо за подсказку [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)
Ведь действительно CASE-ом я просто сортировал поле "lang", которое можно отсортировать и так.

В общем уменьшилось до этого, и решил добавить необязательное поле "id",
чтоб INNER JOIN сравнивал только одну переменную - ведь быстрее будет.

```
[id][id_not_unique][lang][document]

SELECT N.id_not_unique, N.lang, N.document FROM __test_if_else AS N
INNER JOIN
(SELECT S.id FROM
    (SELECT  id, id_not_unique
    from __test_if_else WHERE id_not_unique IN (1,2,3,4,5/*8576*/) AND lang IN ( 'ru','en','it','fr' )
    ORDER BY field (lang, 'fr', 'en', 'it' ) DESC )  AS S 
GROUP BY S.id_not_unique) AS U 
ON N.id = U.id
```

Хотелось бы, конечно, одним SELECT-ом, но если никак, то ...

Comment: Кстати, case можно заменить на `order by field(lang, 'fr', 'en', 'it') desc`. Перечисление в обратном порядке и обратная сортировка потому что функция вернет 0 если не найдет строку

Comment: А получение присутствующего приоритетного языка свести до `select id_not_unique, substr(min(concat(field(lang, 'fr', 'en', 'it'), lang),2,2) lang from __test_if_else where ... group by 1`

Comment: Хм..., Mike, я просто застопорился на этом CASE, а ведь действительно можно было сразу и отсортировать по lang, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = @id
ORDER BY lang = @lang DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я запутался с примерами пока пытался вывести одну строку по условиям, на деле необходимо выводить много строк, т.е. без LIMIT 1. Вопрос поправил.